# Bridge external IP to the qemu standalone Virtual Machine

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualization, interface, qemu

I'm having a very specific issue. To let You know what I'm up to, I will describe the whole infrastructure of my system.

I've got a Ubuntu host machine on which I run up to 4 virtual Ubuntu machines. They are hosted by qemu (standalone, no external managers).
On one of them I need to setup an 'agent' which is written in Java. Agent connects to the controller machine which is somewhere on the external network.
For each virtual machine I've got a TAP interface. All of them are bridged on host to enable communication between virtual machines.

Now what I need to do is to somehow bridge the external IP address to the virtual machine with the agent on it. I can launch the agent with address of NIC interface (ex. 192.168.100.4) or on localhost (127.0.0.1). It can be seen by the controller but I need it to be seen with my host external IP address, not the local one.

```
     |---------|     |---------|     |---------|     |---------|     
     |  VM 1   |     |  VM 2   |     |   VM 3  |     |  VM 4   |
     |  eth0   |     |  eth0   |     |   eth0  |     |  eth0   |
     |---------|     |---------|     |---------|     |---------| 
           \              \               /               /
            \              \---|    |----/               /
             \       |-------------------------|        /
              \------|   tap1 tap2 tap3 tap4   |-------/
                     |     \   |    |    /     |
                     |      \--vmnet1---/      |
                     |                         |
                     |          HOST           |            |---------|  
                     |                     em1 |------------| network |
                     |-------------------------|            |---------|
```

I tried to just pass the external address to the agents config and make some routing on the host with iptables but the agent seems to look at the interfaces when starting and it yells that it cannot see the interface with the given address.

If You have any ideas how to do it I would really appreciate any help! :)

Comment: nice work making that graph)
never saw that ability in standalone qemu, for more options about virtualization i use oracleVM, is that an option to you?

Comment: I'm afraid not. What I tried is virt-manager and virsh. But the problem is I cannot use the same vm images I use with qemu. On virt-manager system just hangs during boot. And virsh... I don't know how to prepare the xml configs to achieve the same functionality as my qemu commands.

Comment: well i don`t see anything helpful other than [this](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking)